# How can i use ajax in an onclick function by react?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, function, onclick

I want to show some result in this function by using ajax. How can I use ajax in an `onclick` function when using React?

```
onItemClick(a) {
  console.log("Button was clicked!");
  var desc = Flightdesc.info.departureinformation.routeshow.description;
  $.ajax({
    url: "/flyrules.inc",
    type: "post",
    data: {
      id: desc
    },
    success: result => {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to achieve or what you are having trouble with. Do you get `result` logged in your console? Do you want to set it in your component state?

Comment: `redux-thunk` is the way to go. It allows to fetch async data via `fetch` (or any other http API like `axios`) https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Answer (score 0):

There are few precautions to apply to your code, I suggest to read the React walkthrough on the official website.

```js
// Bind function to local context with fat arrow
onItemClick = (a) => {
  // Prefer const/let over var
  const desc = Flightdesc.info.departureinformation.routeshow.description;
  $.ajax({
    url: "/flyrules.inc",
    type: "post",
    data: {
      id: desc
    },
    success: result => {
      // setState is an ASYNC function so check the new state in the callback
      this.setState({ data: result }, () => console.log(this.state.data););
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `fetch` API that doesn't require any library to work.

```
onItemClick(a) {
  console.log("Button was clicked!");
  var desc = Flightdesc.info.departureinformation.routeshow.description;

  const yourBaseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000'; // example
  const path = '/flyrules.inc';
  const bodyParams = { id: desc };
  const url = new URL(path, yourBaseUrl);

  fetch('/flyrules.inc', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(bodyParams)
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => data);
}
```